# How to display period class from lubridate in datatable from DT?

Tags: r, datatables, lubridate, dt

I have runtime data for various devices that can be widely different, ranging from a few minutes to several months that I would like to display in a `datatable`. So I thought the `seconds_to_period` function from `lubridate` provides a neat format to print this data. However, I seem unable to display it within a `datatable` from `DT`, which is what I want to do (within a `shiny` App).

Some example data:

```
library(lubridate)
library(DT)

names <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
timevec <- c(225,2250,22500,225000,2250000,22500000)
timevec <- seconds_to_period(timevec)
```

Writing this into a `datatable` without any formatting does not work as it only displays the seconds without considering the minutes/hours etc.:

```
##### This cuts off at the seconds -> useless
table <- data.frame(name = names, time = timevec)
my_table <- datatable(table)
```

Formatting the `time` column with `formatDate` also doesn't work since it is not a `date` or `POSIXct` object. I can print the desired format by typecasting it as a string, but then the sorting of the column doesn't work as it is sorted alphabetically:

```
##### This prints the period format, but sorting does not work
table <- data.frame(name = names, time = as.character(timevec))
my_table <- datatable(table)
```

and of course I could just print the total time in seconds, but as I said I find this very unintuitive to read:

```
##### This prints the seconds -> unintuitive to read
table <- data.frame(name = names, time = as.duration(timevec))
my_table <- datatable(table)
```

Any Ideas on how to achieve this or alternative suggestions how to intuitively display duration data?

Comment: Not a solution with respect to `datatable`, but `table %>% knitr::kable()` preserves the formatting of the periods.

Comment: @Limey Interesting, I will keep that in mind. But right now I think I value the advanced featuers of `datatable` more (sorting, filtering, easier integration with click-events in `shiny`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution by programming DT to sort a shown character column by a hidden numeric column via columnDefs

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)

names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
timevec_raw <- c(225, 2250, 22500, 225000, 2250000, 22500000)
timevec_period <- seconds_to_period(timevec_raw)

(table <- tibble(
  name = names,
  timenum = timevec_raw,
  timechar = as.character(timevec_period)
)
)

my_table <- datatable(table,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, targets = 2
      ), # hide column 2 the numeric one
      list(
        orderData = c(2), # the ordering of column 3 comes from hidden column 2
        targets = c(3)
      )
    )
  )
)
```